# What does a pipe (|) do in a CSS selector?

Tags: css

I found the following definition in a CSS stylesheet :

```
*|*:link {color:#ff00ff;}
```

What's the use of the ***|***? Is it some sort of CSS Hack?

Comment: It's not listed in the [CSS2 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html), so hack... But I'm interested...

Comment: I've never seen a | in a css file before...it must be some sort of hack, because it's not a character in any selector.

Comment: @Jason McCreary @timw4mail The *hack* is called CSS 3 ;)

Comment: Firefox uses it: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/ua.css

Comment: @phihag, I figured as much, but wasn't sure. Hence, *I'm interested*. To be fair, CSS3 is still technically in specification. So this is a *new* selector and probably why this question go so many up votes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It [separates namespace and element name](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#univnmsp).

Unless a default namespace has been defined, `*|*:link` is a complicated way of writing `*:link` or just `:link`.

In an XML document, you could have the following:

```
<el xmlns="http://name/space" />
<style>
@namespace namespace_example url(http://name/space);
namespace_example|el {background: red;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 9):

It is used with namespaces, defining the `namespace|element`. For more information, have a look at the [documentation here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#typenmsp). If there is no `namespace` defined, it is pointless to define the selectors with namespace `*`.

Answer (score 0):

In short it is used to easily target attribute values which are similar upto certain letters,

In a workaround example of different languages,

```
<p lang="en-US">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi iure labore, animi nobis beatae doloribus minus ipsum laborum delectus</p>
<p lang="en-US">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi iure labore, animi nobis beatae doloribus minus ipsum laborum delectus</p>
<p lang="fr-FR">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi iure labore, animi nobis beatae doloribus minus ipsum laborum delectus</p>
<p lang="fr-CA">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi iure labore, animi nobis beatae doloribus minus ipsum laborum delectus</p>
```

If you use pipe selector like this,

```
p[lang|="en"]{
border:1px solid aqua;
}
```

Only first two paragraph will have border.

Here this targeted whichever paragraph attribute value started with "en