# does anybody know what "|" means in CSS selector

Tags: css

on http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation
I found interesting selectors

```
html|*:not(:link):not(:visited)
```

does anybody knows what "|" means.

Comment: You linked to the answer to your question.

Comment: See this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497934/what-does-a-pipe-do-in-a-css-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find more information about it here :

[What | means in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#univnmsp)

It is used to separate namespace and element name in CSS.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 6):

In that same page at 6.2.1, it states that the Vertical bar is for selecting elements in a namespace, (in the above example, the html namespace).

See here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#univnmsp

Answer (score 2):

These questions seems similar to yours : [Using the pipe in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066053/using-the-pipe-in-css) or [What does a pipe (|) do in a CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497934/what-does-a-pipe-do-in-a-css-selector)

> It separates namespace and element name.
>
> Unless a default namespace has been defined, *|*:link is a complicated
>   way of writing *:link or just :link.